# Biztalk 2010, ADFS and CRM 2011 on premises

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, biztalk, crm, adfs, biztalk-2010

I am currently for a client configuring BizTalk 2010 as middleware between Dynamics CRM 2011 on premises with ADFS.

Receiving messages from CRM 2011 to BizTalk is no problem at all.

However the other way around I configured a custom binding as SendPort and can't seem to find the right settings for enforcing HTTPS and authenticating on the ADFS service.

I would imagine that I need settings in the sendport to first authenticate on ADFS and followed on that authenticate against CRM 2011.

Any additional information in regards to this setup and configuration is much appreciated.

Latest sendport information and error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <remove contract="BizTalk" name="WcfSendPort_Crm" />
      <endpoint address="https://crmurl/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" contract="BizTalk" name="WcfSendPort_Crm" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <remove name="EndpointBehavior" />
        <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
          <soapProcessing processMessages="false" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <clear />
        <binding name="ws2007FederationHttpBinding">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-SAMLTokenProfile-01.html">
              <issuer address="https://adfsurl/STS/Active/STS.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="stsBinding">
                <identity>
                  <dns value="STS" />
                </identity>
              </issuer>
              <issuerMetadata address="https://adfsurl/HRGSTS/Active/HRGSTS/mex%22" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Error:

```
A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "WcfSendPort_Crm" with URI "https://crmurl/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" is suspended. 
 Error details: System.InvalidOperationException: The channel is configured to use interactive initializer 'System.ServiceModel.Security.InfocardInteractiveChannelInitializer', but the channel was Opened without calling DisplayInitializationUI.  Call DisplayInitializationUI before calling Open or other methods on this channel.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfInitializationUINotCalled()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.GetChannel[TChannel](IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage, ChannelFactory`1& cachedFactory)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage) 
 MessageId:  {337CB1AF-1C4A-484A-9CA6-7E0FD3396138}
 InstanceID: {FBCDEE5C-8CA2-4C37-87A5-906448C14479}
```

===

```
<ws2007HttpBinding>
    <clear />
    <binding name="ws2007HttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
        establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007HttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the last snippet you've added is the binding to use when calling the STS and that this is the bit you've added to the machine.config as I have at the time - the binding name should be `stsBinding` and not `ws2007HttpBinding` as this should match the name used in the bindingConfiguration attribute of the issuer element in your send port configuration.

Comment: I am still having another issue but as this particular part is resolved. This thread is closed. Thank you yossi

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPS would be Binding, CustomBindingElement, allowInsecureTransport = False

For the ADFS you will probably have to use the Ws2007HttpBinding or reproduce the settings of this in your custom bindings probably setting authenticationMode to IssuedToken and for the IssuedTokenParameter, setting the ADFS address in the Issuer address, binding of ws2007HttpBinding and setting up the binding configuration.

See this blog here [Calling a service with federated identity from BizTalk Server [2009] – Part I](http://blog.sabratech.co.uk/2009/01/calling-service-with-federated-identity.html)

Comment: Hello Dijkgraaf, Thank you for the help till now once more. I added the latest sendport config and error I get. 

Do you see any error in my configuration?

Comment: I see what you mean, I however don't understand exactly what he added the the machine.config when he says "this means that I now need to have another set of binding configuration in my WCF configuration"

I added what I understand I should add on the end of my post once more

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you have set the both the bindingType and the bindingConfiguration to ws2007FederationHttpBinding I would suggest that your bindingConfiguration should be a unique name.  See Referenced bindings in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226446.aspx

Comment: I did not have time to test the solution, the server is unavailable till tomorrow or the day after.